# Get Magento Category URL & Name

Tags: php, magento

I would like to add a few Category links with names manually in my multistore.
I've tried this (Category ID20 as example)

```
<?php $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(20); ?>
<a href="<?php echo $category->getUrl(); ?>"><?php echo $category->getName();?></a>
```

This works, but I'm not sure if it's a good idea, there is a lot of loading just to get URL.

I also tried using translation instead:

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->__('URL-Language1') ?>"><?php echo $this->__('CatName-Language1') ?></a>
```

With translation in the Locale csv.

This also works, but what is the "correct way" to achieve this? This feels like a workaround.

Comment: No, it's not the correct way to do it. Localisations are for language translations. You should keep in mind that while I agree with your statement that the loading of the whole category just to retrieve its name and URL is inefficient, the block you use it in will presumably be cached, so you won't be doing the work every time you load the page.

Comment: Ah thanks, maybe some problem with my cache then, I got 16 categories on different places and when tried with the translation "hack" I got noticeable loading difference, will have to investigate further.

Comment: Another option is to write a resource model that retrieves the data you want directly and exclusively

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category')->getAttributeRawValue($categoryId, 'name', $storeId);
```

for retrieve any category attribute(in this case) also `($categoryId, 'url_key', $storeId)` for url key attribute but it's just url key isn't full category url.